# Can't login to SQL-server using SQLConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

This is really weird, since it have worked great before. "gdb" is my DataContext. Most of the times i use LINQ->SQL to work with my database. But some stuff, like Geography-data isn't supported by LINQ so those queries are executed through old style manual SQL.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(gdb.Connection.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
```

As i said, this have worked before, but not anymore for some reason. Although when testing, it worked one time and then it stopped working again. I get this errormessage:

```
**SQLException was unhandled by code**
Login failed for user 'anton'.
```

The rest of the LINQ->SQL works fine but i can not open that connection for some reason. The SQL-Server is hosted in Azure. And yes, my IP is allowed in the firewall rules!

ASP.Net MVC3 c#

Comment: Sounds like the permissions are not set on the Azure server. I doubt this has anything to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this figured out now! The problem was that i tried to open a new connection before closing the previous one. That seems to be handled automaticly by LINQ->SQL, but LINQ->SQL statements can't be executed when another SQLConnection is open!

Answer (score 0):

you connection string has invalid credentials. Please check that you're using the correct servername, username and password.

```
Server=tcp:[SERVERNAME].database.windows.net;Database=DATABASE;User ID=[USERNAME]@[SERVERNAME];Password=PASSWORD;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;
```

This is how it should be formatted, just replace SERVERNAME, DATABASE, USERNAME and PASSWORD

Comment: It's the exact same connection string as used by LINQ->SQL, which still works fine. Would it be possible then that the SQLConnection alone wouldn't work?

Comment: If it works for one, I would expect it to work for both. Could it possibly be an issue with only allowing 1 concurrent connection?

Comment: Hmm, maybe but it has worked great before, and now it won't work at all. Makes you wonder...

Comment: Yeah very strange, I'm not sure what else this could be. Hopefully the next guy will :)

Comment: It sounds like an issue with your server perhaps, You may be leaving connections opened and they are filling your maximum allowed connections, preventing later connections from working. Can you check this with Azure?

Comment: No unfortunately not, i think...
Azure doesn't have any profiler

Comment: There seem to be something with that i can't execute multiple queries. When i try to execute two queries after each other, only the first one succeeds.